# IQ question - Spades and Clubs inside of boxes

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

This is a question from https://international-iq-test.com/

Here is my attempt at a solution, though it's too convoluted so it's probably wrong:

> Answer is E. The left side and right side combine together to make the middle. Odd numbers + Odd numbers add together. Even numbers + Even numbers add together. Other combinations subtract. Using these rules: 1st row -> 2 clubs - 1 club = 1 club; 2 spades - 1 spades = 1 spade. 2nd row -> 1 club + 1 club = 2 clubs. 2 spades - 1 spade = 1 spade. 3rd row -> 2 clubs - 1 club = 1 club; 2 spades + 0 spades = 2 spades.

[image]

Comment: Also, I think this question is poorly specified (which is the fault of the test creators, not your own fault). The most natural pattern to me is "Each row has the same number of spades in all cells. There are 4 clubs in each row and column." which would lead to the missing box being `♣♣♠♠` - but that's not one of the options.

Comment: Also the locations of clubs and spades seem almost random. Is that intentional or a drawing issue?

Comment: The locations threw me off too; I assumed it was designed to confuse rather than embed any association with the pattern

Comment: @Deusovi - I think you're onto something. What if the pattern is a total of 4 spades and 4 clubs across all rows and columns? Then E is correct

Comment: @Tsdev Ah, I miscounted (and now realize that my second comment makes no sense). Yes, that would explain it.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is the card e.

Every row  and column  has 4 clubs and 4 spade. By adding the card with 2 clubs, we complete the grid.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> E. Look at each figure individually. The pattern is: If a symbol is repeated in the same figure (appears twice), you use subtraction. If a symbol isn't repeated, you use addition.